# Vaadin QuickTickets Dashboard speed of left menu appearances

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I'm investigating Vaadin QuickTickets Dashboard Demo application https://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/ and would like to increase the speed of the left menu appearances on the screen. Could you please show me where this effect can be adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the css properties `animation-delay` and `animation-duration`.
Both are set to 700ms in the demo. They are created via a mixing in common.scss.

On an UX note: Disable the animation completely and always show the menu. While the animation is a nice eye catcher in an presentation. If you need to work with the application regularly, the animation will be a total annoyence.